# Redis or DynamoDB for short living entries used for counting?

Tags: redis, amazon-dynamodb

I want to track the amount of times an action is triggered for a valid JWT token.

Whenever the token is used to trigger an action via the api call, I increment a counter that is stored alongside the token in the persistence layer. The purpose is to limit the amount of actions that it can trigger. After the token expires the entry in the storage has to be deleted.

Normally I would go with Redis, but the problem is that INCR operator doesn't support an optional expire timestamp argument, so everytime I increment the counter for that token I have to check if the value is 1 (this means it was just created) and perform an extra EXPR request via the network.

DynamoDB solves this problem by allowing to define a ttl column, so I can always sent the ttl extracted from the token alongside the increment action without having to check for the first increment (creation of the tuple) . My only concern is that it is not as fast as Redis.

Which strategy do you find to be better? Also please feel free to specify another one if it happens to be better.

Comment: The biggest problem of the ddb solution is that "TTL typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html

Comment: I analyzed this tradeoff and it's no problem. Prior to incrementing the counter, I check for the validity of the token, so if it's expired I don't reach the db.